# How can I convert lambda expression with C#?

Tags: linq, lambda, iqueryable

I need `IQueryable` extension method for my custom query. Example method and I want be result is below. How can I do this ?

Input =>

```
.Where(x => x.Id == 1)
.FilterContent<ProductTranslate>(x => x.ProductName == "product1" 
                                      && x.ShortDescription.Contains("short desc") 
                                      || x.Description.Contains("desc"), 1)
```

Output=>

```
x => (x.Key == "ProductName" && x.Value=="product1")
     && (x.Key == "ShortDescription" && x.Value.Contains("short desc") 
         || (x.Key == "Description" && x.Value.Contains("desc")))
```

Regards.

Comment: Well first, for any given x, x.Key will never equal "ProductName", "ShortDescription", and "Description" all at the same time.  What type do you expect for x? Is it a dictionary or associative array such that the expression would be something like `x => x["ProductName"]=="product1" && x["ShortDescription"].Contains("short desc") || x["Description"].Contains("desc")`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to get a better answer, please provide more details in your question. What is the starting generic type for your `IQueryable<>`? Is it `ProductTranslate`? What is the desired output type? `Func<ProductTranslate, bool>`? `Expression<Func<ProductTranslate, bool>>`? `IQueryable<ProductTranslate>`? `IQueryable<Dictionary<string, string>>`? `Func<KeyValuePair<string, string>, bool>`?

Comment: Side note: Consider whether you need to group the ShortDescription and Description conditions, so a Description match still requires a Productname match. What you have now is: `(product-matches && Short-description-matches) || (description-matches)`.

Comment: i have a LanguageTranslate Table in database. Database scheme is Key-Value. Exc. L
LanguageId =1
Key=ProductName
Value=Water

ProductTranslate class is not entity. it is translate content class. But i get only this class properties from database. I don't want to pull unnecessary records from the database where I don't need to use them. I will only pull the key values ​​of the property in this class. there is no problem in this part. however, I wanted to set up such a structure because the query is very complex where I want to bring the contents of the language I want.

Comment: Strange sample. Do you need to generated dynamically such filter?

Comment: i want dont use complex query in generic repository. therefore i want create an extension methd.

Comment: Show your entities. It is not clear why property names become filter by `x.Key`. It is possible to build/transfer any filter dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are asking, but I will say the solution is way beyond me.

It sounds like to me that you need a function that parses an expression tree of type `Func<Product, bool>` (or more generally `Func<T, TResult>`) and convert it into an expression tree of type `Func<ProductTranslate, bool>` (or more generally `Func<T2, TResult>`).

The article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-modify-expression-trees may be a start. The translation function would walk the original tree and build up a new modified tree. Luckily, it looks like `ExpressionVisitor` base class can do most of the work. You would need check each node to see if it is a `T.Property` reference and replace it with the appropriate `T2.Property`, `T2["Property"]`, `T2.GetPropertyValueByName("Property")` or similar. You may also have to identify and replace whatever node accepts `this T` and an input parameter and replace it with a `this T2` equivalent. Tracking the Product ID and language ID may involve additional changes.

As to how to detect and interpret the `T.Property` node, that may take some digging on your part, but I expect there must be some tools out there to dump expression trees in human readable forms that could help.  Perhaps you can dump an original expression tree and a hand-coded objective expression tree to examine the differences.

If you get through all that, applying the new function to the `IQueryable<>.Where()` function should be the easy part.

P.S., Out of interest, is the following roughly the database structure you are working with, where your ProductTranslateKey class is your in-memory on-demand loaded representation of LanguageTranslate?

Products:

| ID | ProductName | ShortDescription | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Water | Water is good | Water is very good |
| 2 | Fire | Fire is bad | Fire is very bad |

Languages:

| ID | Code | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EN | English |
| 2 | DE | Deutsch |
| 3 | FR | français |

LanguageTranslate:

| ProductID | LanguageId | Key | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ProductName | Water |
| 1 | 1 | ShortDescription | Water is good |
| 1 | 1 | Description | Water is very good |
| 1 | 2 | ProductName | Wasser |
| 1 | 2 | ShortDescription | Wasser ist gut |
| 1 | 2 | Description | Wasser ist sehr gut |
| 1 | 3 | ProductName | Leau |
| 1 | 3 | ShortDescription | Leau est bonne |
| 1 | 3 | Description | Leau est très bonne |
| 2 | 1 | ProductName | Fire |
| 2 | 1 | ShortDescription | Fire is bad |
| 2 | 1 | Description | Fire is very bad |
| 2 | 2 | ProductName | Feuer |
| 2 | 2 | ShortDescription | Feuer ist schlecht |
| 2 | 2 | Description | Feuer ist sehr schlecht |
| 2 | 3 | ProductName | Feu |
| 2 | 3 | ShortDescription | Le feu est mauvais |
| 2 | 3 | Description | Le feu est très mauvais |

Answer (score 0):

My rough database scheme is below. I have a TranslateRecords and TranslateResource tables for covers all entities multilanguage content. I put the translateId column with multiple language options entity table. So I can use all my content in one table without opening a separate translate table for each entity.

I just want to make an extension method because very complex queries occur in the filters I mentioned in the topic.

I will take your suggestions into consideration.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).